# Correlated Sub query gone wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns: Horse and RaceDate. I would like to create a third column that shows for each Horse the number of Racedates that are within 30 days of each RaceDate, that is within 30 days less than each racedate. I'm trying to do this by a correlated sub query but coz i'm comparing one field against a selection of 2 it obviously won't work. I really don't want to revert to treating it as a cursor, is there a solution to this? 
[image]

```
select I.Last30Days,O.Horse,O.RaceDate from Rep2.AuditTrail O
where dateadd(d,-30,O.Racedate) > select I.RaceDate, count(I.RaceDate) as 
Last30Days
from Rep2.AuditTrail I
where I.Horse = O.Horse
group by I.RaceDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `CROSS APPLY` to make it.

```
create table AuditTrail (
  Horse varchar(50),
  Racedate date
);

INSERT INTO AuditTrail VALUES ('AA','2018-01-01');
INSERT INTO AuditTrail VALUES ('AA','2018-02-01');
INSERT INTO AuditTrail VALUES ('AA','2018-03-08');
INSERT INTO AuditTrail VALUES ('AA','2018-04-01');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select O.Horse,O.Racedate,COUNT(Last30Days) Last30Days
from Rep2.AuditTrail O 
CROSS APPLY (
    select I.RaceDate as Last30Days
    from Rep2.AuditTrail I
    where I.Horse = O.Horse AND  DATEDIFF(DAY,i.RaceDate,O.RaceDate)>30
) t1
group by O.Horse,O.Racedate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9c8fd/1/0)**:

```
| Horse |   Racedate | Last30Days |
|-------|------------|------------|
|    AA | 2018-02-01 |          1 |
|    AA | 2018-03-08 |          2 |
|    AA | 2018-04-01 |          2 |
```

Comment: yes, that works!!, just edited your DateDiff criteria to this:DATEDIFF(DAY,i.RaceDate,O.RaceDate) between 1 and 30. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, using sub query in Select

```
select 
  O.Horse,
  O.RaceDate, 
  ( Select Count(*) 
    From AuditTrail 
    Where Horse=O.Horse 
      and DATEDIFF(DAY,RaceDate,O.RaceDate)<=30 ) as Last30Days
from Rep2.AuditTrail O
```